# Android wear: The success animation does not appear after adding a code that starts a new Activity

Tags: android, wear-os

I would like to start an activity after showing a success animation in Android Wear but The success Animation does not appear if I add any code that starts a new Activity.

```
    //SUCCESS ANIMATION
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConfirmationActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_ANIMATION_TYPE,
            ConfirmationActivity.SUCCESS_ANIMATION);
    intent.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE,
            "Ok");
    startActivity(intent);
    //go to NewAtivity
    Intent inten2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent2);
```

Comment: show us how you are starting the animation ??

Comment: @jankigadhiya I'm staring the animation by creating an intent that starts ConfirmationActivity and afterwards I create another intent to start "NewActivity".

Comment: I'm following [this](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/ui/confirm.html#show-confirmation "confirmation")  tutorial. the Confirmation activity appears  if I remove the second part of the code (go to NewAtivity)

Comment: I haven't written any ConfirmationActivity. It's already existed in Android. for more information  [ConfirmationActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/activity/ConfirmationActivity.html  "ConfirmationActivity")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

in your `onCreate()` or wherever the above code is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConfirmationActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_ANIMATION_TYPE,
        ConfirmationActivity.SUCCESS_ANIMATION);
intent.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE,
        "Ok");
startActivityForResult(1,null,intent);
```

outside `onCreate()` create this method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==1)
    {
        Intent inten2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent2);
    }
}
```

**Explanation : The Problem with your Earlier code**

> this line `startActivity(intent);` will start ConfirmationActivity but
>   will not wait for the ConfirmationActivity to get finish but will
>   continue the execution, upon reaching this line
>   `MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent2);` it will start the
>   NewActivity instantly irrespective of the animation has ended or not.

**This solution Helped because :**

> we here used startActivityForResult instead of just startActivity.
>   because of that when the ConfirmationActivity finishes the animation
>   the control returns to your MainActivity and we catch it in
>   onActivityResult and start the NewActivity there.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! it works :)
Could you please tell me what I did wrong in my first code ?

Comment: see the explanation above @Hr.SAAD